# Elements on my website page are affected when I add bootstrap CDN style sheet. *Run Code in Fullscreen*

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

On my webpage, I have the following:

- Navigation
- A Banner
- An About Section
- A services section

The reason for adding the bootstrap CDN on this page was as a result of a modal popup I wanted on the page.

I started fooling around the code and noticed when I edited out the CDN, everything on the page went back to normal.

The sections of the page that got affected was the services section, they suddenly floated a tad bit to the right and the heading was a bit messed up.

Even the color of the about section changed and the text went missing.

```css
/* ===== FONTS ===== */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@800&display=swap');

body {
    background-color: black;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.banner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491421722235-b556e8f64dab?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80');
    background-size: cover;
}


.banner h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin: 0 0 1.2em;
    padding-top: 2.5em;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #00bfff;
}

.banner h1 span {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    color: crimson;
}

.banner p {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 4em 0 0;
}

.top {
    padding-left: 3em;
}

.top {
    animation: fadeIn 2s forwards;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .banner {
     width: 100%;
     background: url('images/DSC01925.jpg') 55% no-repeat;
 
 }

 .banner h1 {
     font-size: 2rem;
     margin: 0.5em 0 1em 0;
     padding-top: 10em;
     /* padding-bottom: 2.5em; */
     text-align: left;
     color: #00bfff;
     display: inline-block;
 }
 
 .banner h1 span {
     text-transform: uppercase;
     display: block;
     font-size: 1.5rem;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1;
     color: crimson;
 }

}



/* ======== NAVIGATION ======== */
 
  nav {
    background: black;
    padding: 5px 40px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    /*left: 0;*/
    width: 100%;
    /*justify-content: space-between;*/
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.6s;
    z-index: 100000;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  nav.sticky {
    padding: 20px 100px;
    background: /*#235d63*/
    black;
  }
  
  nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  nav ul li {
    padding: 15px 0;
  }
  
  nav ul li.items {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 16px;
    text-align: center;
    order: 3;
  }
  
  nav ul li.items::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    left: 0;
    bottom: 5px;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    color: cyan;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  nav ul li.items:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
    bottom: 8px;
  }
  
  nav ul li.logo {
    flex: 1;
    color: cyan;
    font-size: 1.4375rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    transition: .4s;
  }
  
  nav ul li a {
    color: slategray;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  
  nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: cyan;
    color: slategray !important;
    font-weight: 700;
    transition: all ease 0.4s;
  }
  
  nav ul li i {
    font-size: 23px;
  }
  
  nav ul li.btn {
    display: none;
    color: cyan;
  }
  
  nav ul li.btn.show i::before {
    content: '\f00d';
  }

  @media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
    nav {
      padding: 5px 30px
    }
    nav ul li.items {
      width: 100%;
      display: none;
    }
    nav ul li.items.show {
      display: block;
    }
    nav ul li.btn {
      display: block;
    }
    nav ul li.items:hover {
      border-radius: 5px;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px cyan;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px cyan;
    }
    nav ul li.items:hover::after {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }


#myModal {
    padding-top: 4em;
    justify-content: center;
}

.modal-body img {
    padding: 1em 30px;
    justify-content: center;
    height: auto;
    width: 470px;
}



/* ==================== About Section - START ==================== */

#about {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 50px 5% 0px 5%;
    background-color: white;
}

.about-text {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    width: 50%;
}

.about-text h1 {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    color: cyan;
    /* text-transform: uppercase; */
}

.about-text h1 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.about-text p {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: white;
}

.about-model-img img {
    width: 350px;
    height: auto;
}

.about-text button {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    width: 180px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 1000;
    background-color: cyan;
}

.about-text button:hover {
    background-color: white;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #about {
        padding-top: 5em;
        padding-bottom: 30em;
        
        
    }

    .about-text h1 {
        font-size: 6em;
        margin-top: 6em;
    }
    
    .about-text p {
        font-size: 1rem;
        
    }

    .about-text button {
        margin-top: 2rem;
        width: 120px;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        color: black;
        font-size: 0.8rem;
        font-weight: 800;
        background-color: cyan;
    }
}

@media(max-width:1190px) {
    .about-model img {
        
        top: 50%;
    }
}

@media(max-width:970px) {
   
     .about-model-img {
        display: none;
    }

    #about {
        justify-content: center;
        padding-top: 0px;
        height: 40vh;
    }

    .about-text {
        width: 90%;
    }

    .about-text h1 {
        font-size: 4rem;
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
        
    }

    .p-container{
        width:100%;
    
    }
}

/* ==================== Our Services Section - START ==================== */

.container {
    background: white;
    font-family: 'Montserrat' , 'sans-serif';
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container .heading {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    /* margin-top: 40px; */
    color: #45a29e;
}

.heading h2::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: black;
    bottom: 0;
    left: calc(50% - 75px);
}

.heading h2::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #66fcf1;
    border: 4px solid black;
    left: calc(50% - 12px);
    bottom: -7px;
}

.services-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 50px;
    margin-left: 180px;
}

.services-container .card {
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
    background: black;
    display: flex;
    width: 45%;
    margin: 30px 0;
}

.services-container .card .imgBx {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #45a29e;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.services-container .card:hover .imgBx {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    left: -90px;
    top: calc(50% - 75px);
    background: #45a29e;
    font-size: 0;
    /* border-radius: 50%; */
}

.services-container .card .imgBx::before {
    content: attr(data-text);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 27%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    font-weight: 700;
}

.services-container .card .imgBx img {
    max-width: 100px;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.services-container .card:hover .imgBx img {
    max-width: 75px;
}

.services-container .card .info {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 75px);
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    left: 11%;
}

.services-container .card .info h3 {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: cyan;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.services-container .card .info a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #45a29e;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.services-container .card .info a:hover {
    background: white;
    color: #45a29e;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #45a29e;
}

.copyright {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px 27% 0px 27%;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

/* ===== MAIN Responsiveness ===== */

@media(max-width:970px) {
            
    .p-container{
                grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
            grid-template-rows:auto;
            grid-gap: 10px;
                height: auto;
    }
}



@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .services-container {
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        margin-left: 50%;
    }

    .services-container .card {
        width: 400px;
    }

    
    .services-container .card .imgBx {
        position: relative;
        background-color: cyan;
    }

    .services-container .card .info {
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .services-container .card .info h3 {
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .services-container .card .imgBx, 
    .services-container .card:hover .imgBx {
        width: 100%;
        height: 250px;
        left: 0;
    }

    .services-container .card .imgBx .imgBx, 
    .services-container .card:hover .imgBx img {
        max-width: 100px;
    }

    .services-container .card .info {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .services-container .card .imgBx::before {
        font-size: 0;
    }
}


@media (max-width: 972px) {
    .services-container {
        /* width: 100%; */
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    .services-container .card {
        width: 400px;
    }

    
    .services-container .card .imgBx {
        position: relative;
        background-color: cyan;
    }

    .services-container .card .info {
        font-size: 10px;
        left: 1%;
    }

    .services-container .card .info h3 {
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .services-container .card .imgBx, 
    .services-container .card:hover .imgBx {
        width: 100%;
        height: 250px;
        left: 0;
    }

    .services-container .card .imgBx .imgBx, 
    .services-container .card:hover .imgBx img {
        max-width: 100px;
    }

    .services-container .card .info {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .services-container .card .imgBx::before {
        font-size: 0;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {

    .services-container .card {
        max-width: 300px;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: auto;
    }

    .services-container .card .imgBx {
        position: relative;
        background-color: cyan;
    }

    .services-container .card .info {
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .services-container .card .info h3 {
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .services-container .card .imgBx, 
    .services-container .card:hover .imgBx {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        left: 0;
    }

    .services-container .card .imgBx .imgBx, 
    .services-container .card:hover .imgBx img {
        max-width: 100px;
    }

    .services-container .card .info {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .services-container .card .imgBx::before {
        font-size: 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Company Name</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/js/all.min.js"> -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@latest/dist/boxicons.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c8e4d183c2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>

<!-- ===== MODAL SECTION ===== -->

    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Check Out Our Music!</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1471029093449-ca61fffdc2af?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Subscribe</button>
                   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<!-- ===== NAVIGATION SECTION ===== -->

     <header>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li class="logo">LOGO</li>
            <li class="items"><a href="#" class="active">HOME</a></li>
            <li class="items"><a href="#">TEAM</a></li>
            <li class="items"><a href="#">MERCH</a></li>
            <li class="items"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li class="btn"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    
          <div class="page-wrapper">
            <section class="banner">
                <div class="top">
                <h1>Company Name<span>Address</span></h1>
                </div>
            </section>
        
            

        <!-- ===== ABOUT SECTION ===== -->
        
        <section id="about">
            <div class="about-text">
                <h1>About Us</h1><br>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ultrices euismod mattis. Ut non mi mauris. Nam condimentum turpis vitae arcu vestibulum lacinia.<br><br>We are heavily invested into this and are continuously looking at ways to improve our craft and contribute to the music scene in Jamaica and its further development.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ultrices euismod mattis. Ut non mi mauris. Nam condimentum turpis vitae arcu vestibulum lacinia.</p>

                <button>Contact Us</button>

            </div>

            <div class="about-model-img">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508341546836-3a53fe49413a?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=752&q=80" alt="">
            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- ===== SERVICES SECTION ===== -->
        <section class="container">
            <div class="heading">
                <h2>Our Services</h2>
            </div>
        <div class="services-container">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="imgBx" data-text="Recording Sessions">
                    <img src="https://www.flaticon.com/svg/vstatic/svg/3126/3126425.svg?token=exp=1612227542~hmac=878e47b14dec39febb9c13bb702183a3" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <div>
                        <h3>Recording Sessions</h3>
                        <a href="servicesinquiry.html">Inquire</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="imgBx" data-text="Production">
                    <img src="https://www.flaticon.com/svg/vstatic/svg/3126/3126425.svg?token=exp=1612227542~hmac=878e47b14dec39febb9c13bb702183a3" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <div>
                        <h3>Production</h3>
                        <a href="#">Inquire</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="imgBx" data-text="Mastering">
                    <img src="https://www.flaticon.com/svg/vstatic/svg/3126/3126425.svg?token=exp=1612227542~hmac=878e47b14dec39febb9c13bb702183a3" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <div>
                        <h3>Mastering</h3>
                        <a href="servicesinquiry.html">Inquire</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>   
            
            <div class="card">
                <div class="imgBx" data-text="Mixing">
                    <img src="https://www.flaticon.com/svg/vstatic/svg/3126/3126425.svg?token=exp=1612227542~hmac=878e47b14dec39febb9c13bb702183a3" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <div>
                        <h3>Mixing</h3>
                        <a href="#">Inquire</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>
        </section>      

        <footer>
            <p class="copyright">&copy; Company Name </p>
        </footer>

<!-- Responsive Navigation Menu -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.btn').click(function() {
                $('.items').toggleClass("show");
                $('ul li').toggleClass("hide");
            })
            });        
</script>

<!-- JAVASCRIPT Code for Sticky Navigation Menu -->
<script>
    window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
        var header = document.querySelector("nav");
        header.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0)
    })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what bootstrap is all about. You include the bootstrap css and all elements get a basic styling (aka your page stylings get bootstrapped). This is because bootstrap defines styles for all those elements.

When working with bootstrap you have to make sure that your custom styles don't conflict with those of bootstrap by defining your CSS properties with the right element selectivity. The first thing you can try is to include bootstrap first and your custom styles thereafter.

But I noticed some things in your own code:

The About-text is not missing. It has white color on white background. So you can't see it. This comes from your own styles and has nothing to do with bootstrap.

From your CSS:

```
#about {
    background-color: white;
}

/* ... */

.about-text p {
    color: white;
}
```

You should clean up your style sheets.

Comment: Thank you, I'll definitely go ahead and clean it up. Still having issues with getting the modal to not mess everything up, but I'll either create and style my own or continue messing with the code.